# Ver como foi escrito as funções nativas

Tags: python, funções

Existe uma maneira prática de verificar, como está escrito o código de uma função qualquer do Python, exemplo `max()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quando é uma função escrita em Python, você pode utilizar o módulo [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource).

Por exemplo:

```
def somar(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Ao fazer `print(inspect.getsource(somar))` você terá a saída como *string*:

```
def somar(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Isso funcionará para módulos, classes, métodos, funções e outros; só não funcionará para objetos que foram implementados em C, como por exemplo o módulo `sys` e as funções `min` e `max`. Para isso, você precisará olhar nos arquivos de código fonte, no [repositório oficial](https://github.com/python/cpython).

Se a intenção é analisar a fundo o que acontece, sugiro utilizar o módulo [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html). Com ele você consegue, por exemplo, verificar o *opcode* que será executado pelo interpretador:

```
>>> print( dis.dis(somar) )
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              4 BINARY_ADD
              6 RETURN_VALUE
None
```

O que cada comando significa você pode ler na documentação.

Answer (score 4):

Todo código fonte do Python (implementação padrão) [está no Github](https://github.com/python/cpython) e pode ser consultado. A função [`max()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/80b762f010097ab8137782e5fbdc89c5c620ed4e/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1706).